# Set "modifier" and "attribute" as synonyms of "modifiers"

Tags: support, status-completed, retag-request

[modifier](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/modifier) and [attribute](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/attribute) (or [attributive](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/attributive)) could be set as synonyms of [modifiers](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/modifiers).

*Modifier* should have a meaning that includes the meaning of *attribute*, or *attributive*, even though *attributive* is used to refer an adjective (or a noun) preceding the word it modifies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks complete to me at this point.

Comment: Just [tag:modifier] is a synonym of [tag:modifiers]; the other two are not synonyms.